# C# change font attributes of trayMenu item

Tags: c#, fonts

I want to change different font attributes of some trayMenu items, but I don't know how and google obviously doesn't like me.

I create my trayMenu items like this:

```
trayMenu.Items.Add(Resources.DUMMY).MouseUp += (s, e) => HandleDUMMY(e);
```

trayMenu is declared like this:

```
private static readonly ContextMenuStrip trayMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();
```

The content of "Resources.DUMMY" is in my "Resources.resx" file, the entry looks like this:

```
<data name="DUMMY" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>this is a dummy</value>
</data>
```

The font attributes I'd like to change are the font size, color, thickness etc.pp.
Also it would be nice to be able to change the space between the different trayMenu entries.

Comment: is this winforms?

Comment: tbh i have no idea whats the difference in winforms/wpf ism but i'm using winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got the solution now. You have to create a variable for every Item you add, then acess the variable.

```
var dummy = trayMenu.Items.Add(Resources.DUMMY);
dummy.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 10F);
dummy.MouseUp += (s, e) => HandleDUMMY(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you  look at MSDN,lays it all out for you:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip(v=vs.110).aspx

all the properties you need are accessible. As for the distance between items, you can easily set a margin for each item

Edit: For resources, just do Resources.Key to access

Edit 2: If you want to manually edit each item, simply edit the item as it is added, by manually adding ToolStripItem

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well, I can use trayMenu.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("", 12F); to change the font size of ALL the entries, but i want to make some thick, and some not etc.